# Left Semi Join on Geo-Spatial tables in Spark-SQL & GeoMesa

Tags: apache-spark-sql, geospatial, geomesa

**Problem:**

I have 2 tables (d1 & d2) containing Geo-spatial points. I want to carry out the following query:

```
select * from table 1 where table1.point is within 50km of any point in table2.point
```

I am using `Spark-SQL` with `GeoMesa` & `Accumulo` to achieve the same. (Spark as processing engine, Accumulo as Data Store & GeoMesa for GeoSpatial libraries).

The above query is kind of **`left semi join`** but I am not sure on how to achieve it using `Spark-SQL` because as far as I have read subqueries can't be used in where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve this using:

```
select * from d1 left semi join d2 on st_contains(st_bufferPoint(d1.point, 10000.0), d2.point)
```

Spark broadcasted d2 & is carrying out joins but it is still taking more time as the size of d1 is 5 billion & d2 is 10 million.

Not sure though if there is any more efficient way to achieve the same.